# ELSE IF em campo calculado do sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Como utilizar uma estrutura `ELSE IF` em um campo calculado do Sharepoint, por exemplo:

```
= IF([Nota]>=80,"A")
  ELSEIF([Nota]>=70,"B")
  ELSEIF([Nota]>50,"C")
  ELSEIF([Nota]>=30,"D")
  ELSE("E")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso é necessário aninhar vários `IF`s:

```
=IF([Nota]>=80;
   "A";
   IF([Nota]>=70;
      "B";
      IF([Nota]>50;
         "C";
         IF([Nota]>=30;
            "D";
            "E"
         )
      )
   )
)
```

<sub>Código identado apenas para entendimento, não tenho certeza se o Sharepoint permite.</sub>

**Obs.:** Note que o **separador na versão em português é `;` um ponto e vírgula,** já na versão inglês é uma `,`.